# Reading current with ACS712: output range from 0 to 2.5 V with 1.25 V center, no load

Tags: adc, current-measurement

I would like to measure current using a ACS712-20A sensor from an ATMEGA328P that has its AREF set as 2.5V from a TL431 voltage reference.

As the ATMEGA328P is set to read a range between 0V and 2.5V.

Should I be powering the ACS712 sensor from a stable 5V supply and halving the output with a voltage divider resistor pair giving me a no load reading of 1.25V and a range from 0V to 2.5V?

Or should I be powering the ACS712 from 2.5V giving me an output that should already match the ADC of my ATMEGA between 0V and 2.5V?

Why should I be powering the ACS712 from an independent regulator for stability / accuracy rather than from the main LVR of my circuit?

The circuit in question currently runs from a 55V battery that uses a LM2596HVGR to produce 12V that powers L78M05ABDT outputting 5V that produces its 2.5V reference with the TL431.

I do not want to change the reference to the ATMEGA as it is also used for measuring other ADC inputs.

Answer (score 1):

From this [datasheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs712-datasheet.pdf) the following information about power supply voltage can be found:

[image]

And this is the output voltage range (not 0V to 5V):

[image]

Moved from the comments: this device has a "ratiometric output from supply voltage" which means that this voltage will vary with changes in Vcc. Evaluate this source of error together with all the other ones mentioned in the datasheet to see if it fits your accuracy requirements. The voltage divider with equal resistors will reduce the range to 250 mV to 2.25V, which must be considered for your accuracy calculation. To understand as much as possible about the sensor, I'd kindly recommend the linked datasheet.

Comment: appreciated, while that rules out option 1 it does not answer how i can read the output from a 2.5v reference. would my idea of an equal voltage resistor divider be sufficient and if not is there any other approach to halfing the output voltage in order to read it from a 2.5v reference, my dilema is these sensors are expensive, my circuit has 2 sensors and JLC have a minimum order of 5 PCBs, i would like to understand as much as possible about them before ordering boards with 10 chips that dident turn out much use. many thanks

Comment: also my understanding is that the output mid point is exactly half the input voltage so i amuse it needs to be powered from an accurate steady 5v supply not the same VCC that is powering the ATMEGA, could this be true?

Comment: The idea is that it is powered from the same supply as the adc reference, thus you get a ratiometric conversion. Note you can change the mega328 reference via code - you just need some time to let vref settle if using a capacitor on the vref pin. Or just use a 2:1 resistor divider as you’ve suggested.